# Read operation exception MongoDB in EC2, but local is ok

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

My web app and mongo built in different ec2.

I run web app in localhost and connect mongo in ec2. 
It's OK.

but I deploy web app in ec2.
It have exception

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /172.XX.XX.XX:27017 failed on database 
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:253)
com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
com.google.code.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.hasNext(MorphiaIterator.java:43)
com.google.code.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:286)
```

my monogo congig

```
<bean id="mongoOptions" class="com.mongodb.MongoOptions">
<property name="autoConnectRetry" value="false" />
<property name="maxAutoConnectRetryTime" value="0" />
<property name="connectionsPerHost" value="10" />
<property name="connectTimeout" value="10000" />
<property name="cursorFinalizerEnabled" value="true" />
<property name="maxWaitTime" value="120000" />
<property name="threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier" value="5" />
<property name="socketTimeout" value="0" />
<property name="socketKeepAlive" value="false" />
<property name="safe" value="true" />
<property name="w" value="0" />
<property name="wtimeout" value="0" />
<property name="fsync" value="false" />
<property name="j" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow.com has an audience of programmers. When you have a server configuration problem, you should seek help on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Set the network security in the EC2 configuration to allow MongoDb traffic through to your DB box, the default is 27017.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes by (because I did) I was stuck on this same problem of mongodb connecting on local but not on my ec2 server.. for hours.. here is the solution and it's very simple.

When you created the MongoDB cluster, you added your computer's IP address to the white list. You need to grab EC2 Instance's 'IPv4 Public IP' and add that to to the white list as well.